# KMP algorithm implementations in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I have seen several implementations of this algorithm, for example the one with 2 counters and iteration over prefix or the one that uses recursion. However, I have some difficulty understanding the one that uses dynamic programming.

Due to my shallow knowledge, this is what I managed to come up with:

```py
def sufperf(S):
    Pi = [0 for i in range(len(S))]
    for i in range(1, len(S)):
        p = Pi[i - 1]
        while p > 0 and S[i] != S[p]:
            p = Pi[p-1]
        if S[i] == S[p]:
            p += 1
        Pi[i] = p
    return Pi


def KMP(S, subS):
    NewS = subS + "#" + S
    SuperS = sufperf(NewS)
    k = 0
    for i in SuperS:
        if i == len(subS):
            k += 1
    return k
```

I have some trouble completely understanding logic in KMP function. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: what is your input with S, subS

Comment: I ran several test with  S = "abcdaaabcabcaa" and subS = "abc", 

S = "Suppose you have an array of 99 numbers. The array contains the digits 1 to 100 with one digit missing. Describe four different algorithms to compute the missing number. Two of these should optimize for low storage and two of these should optimize for fast processing."
subs = "missing"

Comment: KMP is not a dynamic programming based algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using knowledge about the string is essentially the base of all string searching algorithms,there's something you know about the string already and you try to utilize this "heuristic", if you will, to save yourself time searching.

KMP in particular utilizes the fact that if we know that a suffix matches a prefix. So in the example where we're looking `var needle` in `var haystack`

`String we're looking for (Needle)
 abczabcd 
 12345678`

`String we're looking in (Haystack)
 abcz abcb a  b  c  d   a  b  c  z 
 1234 5678 9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 -> indices`

We go through `abczabcb`, and then we hit the `b`(index 10 of haystack) instead of a `d`(index 8 of needle).

Using this suffix/prefix rule from KMP, we don't have to go all the way back to `b` to search for `abc`, instead we can utilize the fact that `abcb` has the prefix `abc`, and start checking at `b` to see if it's equal to `z`.

It's not so we can skip `abczabcb`, not having to search for the string we're looking for again from indices 2,3,4,5,6,7,8

I personally really like BacktoBackSWE's youtube channel, his explanation of KMP is very clear and easy to understand.

Resources:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BXCEFAzhxGY

https://medium.com/@pivincii/pattern-searching-algorithm-knuth-morris-pratt-aka-kmp-algorithm-13f4a9fd968b

Another string searching algorithm, Boyer-Moore, uses the good suffix and bad character rules. I mention this because I think it's a good observation that all these string matching algorithms are similar in the sense that they use knowledge about the string.

The wiki goes into this further :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm#Shift_rules

GeeksForGeeks also has a good resource on this :

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/boyer-moore-algorithm-good-suffix-heuristic/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/boyer-moore-algorithm-for-pattern-searching/